# Problem about fibonacci sequence via quadratic roots in gelfand's algebra text.Need hints.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, fibonacci-numbers

I have solved a preceding question proving that the common ratio of such a sequence is $ \frac {1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $ or $ \frac {1-\sqrt{5}}{2} $ (resolving a quadratic equation) . The present problem is to find A and B such that (for all n) the nth term of the fibonacci sequence is $ A(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n + B(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n $. How do i approach the problem?

Comment: Well you already have $F_0=1,F_1=1$

Comment: True.What next? Doesn't the sequence start _after_ those two terms?

Comment: @AdityaChintalapati: no, it starts already with them. In particular, your choice of $A,B$ is uniquely defined by these first two terms: taking $n=0$  in the formula should give $F_0$, taking $n=1$ should give $F_1$.

Comment: @kingW3:   A=$\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2\sqrt{5}}$ and B =$ \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2\sqrt{5}}$. Can you please verify ?

Comment: This is correct